# Ubuntu Linux Library Path

Tags: c++, linux, linker

How do I determine the Ubuntu Linux Library Path? That is, how does the linker know where to got to grab the object files when linking my program?

Answer (score 13):

Look at `/etc/ld.so.conf` and the files in the `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/` directory -- that's where it is set.

Answer (score 8):

The file paths can be set explicitly when linking using the `-L` parameter, as well as the environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

There are also some paths hard-coded into the linker, using the `-L` param.  You can see these with the command:

```
gcc -Xlinker -v
```

Answer (score 6):

If it's not a standard path (`/lib`, `/usr/lib`), you can specify the location with the compiler flag. For `g++`, it's `-L/some/path/lib`. If you use autotools, you can just configure with `LDFLAGS=-L/some/path/lib` if you need a specific path. If configure has been properly designed for the project, it should have a `--with-some-library=PATH` option, where you can also specify a path for that library only.

Answer (score 5):

When linking, you need to specify the -L flag to indicate where the library is located. At runtime, the dynamic linker uses the paths given in "/etc/ld.so.conf", "/etc/ld.so.conf.d/*" and the value of LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

Answer (score 4):

"sudo ldconfig" updates the system's cache if you've just installed something new.